# Bash fg command with pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

Is it possible to run an `fg` or a `bg` or a `jobs` command in bash in a pipeline?

What possible inputs/outputs can those commands do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `help fg` and `help bg` to answer these qestions.

Briefly, no you can't use them in a pipeline (and what would you expect this to do?)

They don't have any output, to my knowledge.

I recommend you `man bash` and read the JOB CONTROL section.

Comment: And [Process Management in Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).